# How to map values with multiple variable conditions between two dataframes (without iterrows)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking to map multiple variable conditions between two data-frames. I have a solution which works quite nicely, but I am sure there is a more efficient method of achieving my goal. I have a dataframe containing a column of employees df1['SN'] with shift dates df1['shift_date'].  I have another set of data which describes the contract df2['con_type'] type the employee was on across a date range df2[['con_start_date', 'con_end_date']]. What i want to do, is to map the contract type the employee was on, on their shift date.

df1:

```
    SN      shift_date  
0   ID1     2020-01-02
1   ID1     2020-01-03
2   ID1     2020-01-06
3   ID1     2020-01-20
4   ID1     2020-01-21
5   ID2     2020-01-03
6   ID2     2020-01-04
```

df2:

```
    SN      con_start_date  con_end_date    con_type
0   ID1     2013-12-31      2020-01-07      FT
1   ID1     2020-01-08      2020-12-31      PT
2   ID2     2019-12-04      2020-12-31      FT
```

with the outcome df3:

```
    SN      shift_date  con_type
0   ID1     2020-01-02  FT
1   ID1     2020-01-03  FT
2   ID1     2020-01-06  FT
3   ID1     2020-01-20  PT
4   ID1     2020-01-21  PT
5   ID2     2020-01-03  FT
6   ID2     2020-01-04  FT
```

current solution which works nicely:

```
for index,rows in df2.iterrows():
    df3=df1.copy()  
    filter1=(df1['SN']==rows['SN'])
    filter2=(df1['Date']>=rows['con_start_date'])
    filter3=(df1['Date']<rows['con_end_date'])
    mask=filter1 & filter2 & filter3
    df1.loc[mask,'con_type']=rows['con_type']
```

However, while I have a solution that works, I am convinced there is a better way to do it? Iterrows is notoriously in-efficient compared to other methods :(. Also, if there is a better title, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using apply

What about using `apply` instead of `iterrows`?
You can define a function like this:

```py
def get_type(x):
    # Get the appropriate value from df2.
    filter1=(x['SN']==df2['SN'])
    filter2=(x['shift_date']>=df2['con_start_date'])
    filter3=(x['shift_date']<df2['con_end_date'])
    df_temp = df2[filter1 & filter2 & filter3]
    return df_temp['con_type'].iloc[0]
```

and then apply it like this:

```py
df1['con_type'] = df1.apply(get_type, axis=1)
```

### Using native pandas

To use "vectorized" operations, the rows need to be lined up first. You can achieve this by doing an outer join on `SN`:

```py
df_new = df1.merge(df2, on=['SN'], how='outer')
```

so that now, for each row with `SN` equal to the one in the first frame, you will have all the information from all rows from the second frame that match this ID:

```
     SN  shift_date con_start_date con_end_date con_type
0   ID1  2020-01-02     2013-12-31   2020-01-07       FT
1   ID1  2020-01-02     2020-01-08   2020-12-31       PT
2   ID1  2020-01-03     2013-12-31   2020-01-07       FT
3   ID1  2020-01-03     2020-01-08   2020-12-31       PT
4   ID1  2020-01-06     2013-12-31   2020-01-07       FT
5   ID1  2020-01-06     2020-01-08   2020-12-31       PT
6   ID1  2020-01-20     2013-12-31   2020-01-07       FT
7   ID1  2020-01-20     2020-01-08   2020-12-31       PT
8   ID1  2020-01-21     2013-12-31   2020-01-07       FT
9   ID1  2020-01-21     2020-01-08   2020-12-31       PT
10  ID2  2020-01-03     2019-12-04   2020-12-31       FT
11  ID2  2020-01-04     2019-12-04   2020-12-31       FT
```

Now everything is lined up for the native pandas operations:

```py
df_new = df1.merge(df2, on=['SN'], how='outer')
df_new = df_new.query('con_start_date <= shift_date < con_end_date').reset_index(drop=True)
df_new.drop(columns=['con_start_date', 'con_end_date'], inplace=True)
```

For the small example frame, this did work faster, though I'm not sure about the performance of merge if your tables are really large.

Comment: dont you need to send `x` to `get_type`?

Comment: 'df1' is passed by default since it's to the left of the dot before 'apply'.

Comment: nosuchthingasmagic, Joe Ferndz. These answers are good, they both do a better job than my solution. Is there any real way to 'Vectorize' the code, as from my limited understanding, vectorisation is exponentially better than either itterrows, or apply. Thanks

Comment: @twillk Good question. Usually, "vectorized" operations using native pandas operations require the data to be lined up by row, but there is a roundabout way of doing it. I will add it to my response.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function and use that to check the value. Here's how I did it.

```
def checkConType(x):
    for i,v in df2.iterrows():
        if (v.SN == x.SN) and \
           (v.con_start_date <= x.shift_date) and \
           (v.con_end_date >= x.shift_date):
            return v.con_type

df1['con_type'] = df1.apply(lambda x: checkConType(x), axis=1)

print (df1)
```

The output of this is:

```
    SN shift_date con_type
0  ID1 2020-01-02       FT
1  ID1 2020-01-03       FT
2  ID1 2020-01-06       FT
3  ID1 2020-01-20       PT
4  ID1 2020-01-21       PT
5  ID2 2020-01-03       FT
6  ID2 2020-01-04       FT
```